# How to pass an empty list to the parameter?

Tags: python, flask-restful

You need to send a list to the server. If the list is not empty, everything works fine:

```
from flask_restful import reqparse, Resource
import requests

class CitizensPatch(Resource):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('towns', required=False, action='append', type=int)

def patch(self, a, b):
    args = self.parser.parse_args()
    print(args)  # {'requests': [1, 2, 3]}
```

from test file:

```
patch_json = {
    'relatives': [1, 2, 3]
}
    print(requests.patch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/a/1/b/2', json=patch_json).json())
```

But if we pass an empty list, it is parsed as none type:

```
from flask_restful import reqparse, Resource
import requests

class CitizensPatch(Resource):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('towns', required=False, action='append', type=int)

def patch(self, a, b):
    args = self.parser.parse_args()
    print(args)  # {'relatives': None}
```

From test file:

```
patch_json = {
    'relatives': []
}
print(requests.patch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/a/1/b/2', json=patch_json).json())
```

You need to empty the array in relatives was parcels as an empty array and not as None. How to do this? Can pass some other parameter to parser.add_argument?

Answer (score 1):

Just make it an optional parameter and just send it to the html if the list is not empty.

Answer (score -1):

Egor, Hello!! 
Do you watch "KO"?
Good bye!